# How to use wxshaped window and png with transparency in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, transparency, shaped-window

Edit: Found out how to place a **transparent wxPanel** on my **shaped frame**, but now ı try to put a **wxGridBagSizer** on the **wxPanel** with some widgets in it but only the first widget will appear...Any ideas?

Original question :

Well I'm trying to make a **wx.ShapedWindow** with a **png background** that has **transparency**, the problem is that it looks like they **changed the wx lib** so to set the shape on the bitmap before we could use **wx.RegionFromBitmap()** but this is not working anymore, i tried to use **wx.Region** only but i can't figure out how to have the transparency ! I have a grey zone where i would like transparent region....

If anyone can help me !

Here's what i get now :

```
import wx
from os import getcwd

class ShapedFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "Shaped Window", style = wx.FRAME_SHAPED | wx.SIMPLE_BORDER )
        self.hasShape = False
        self.delta = wx.Point(0,0)
        ImgDir = (getcwd()+u"\\img\\ex.png")
        self.bmp = wx.Image(ImgDir, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        w,h = self.bmp.GetWidth(), self.bmp.GetHeight()
        self.SetClientSize(w,h)
        #self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1,size=(100,100))
        panel = Panel(self)
        panel.Show()
        dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
        dc.DrawBitmap(self.bmp, 0,0, True)
        self.SetWindowShape()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK, self.OnDoubleClick)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnLeftDown)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.OnLeftUp)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMouseMove)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_UP, self.OnExit)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_WINDOW_CREATE, self.SetWindowShape)

################# EDIT ONLY BUTTON 0 WILL APPEAR ########################
        button0 = wx.Button(panel, -1, "hello 0")
        button1 = wx.Button(panel, -1, "hello 1")
        button2 = wx.Button(panel, -1, "hello 2")
        button3 = wx.Button(panel, -1, "hello 3")

        gbox7 = wx.GridBagSizer(0,0)
        gbox7.SetEmptyCellSize((10,10))
        gbox7.Add(button0,(0,0))
        gbox7.Add(button1,(0,1))
        gbox7.Add(button2,(1,0))
        gbox7.Add(button3,(1,1))

        panel.SetSizer(gbox7)

#######################################################################
    
    def SetWindowShape(self, evt=None):
        r = wx.Region(self.bmp,wx.TransparentColour)
        self.hasShape = self.SetShape(r)

    def OnDoubleClick(self, evt):
        if self.hasShape:
            self.SetShape(wx.Region())
            self.hasShape = False
        else:
            self.SetWindowShape()

    def OnPaint(self, evt):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.DrawBitmap(self.bmp, 0,0, True)

    def OnExit(self, evt):
        self.Close()

    def OnLeftDown(self, evt):
        self.CaptureMouse()
        pos = self.ClientToScreen(evt.GetPosition())
        origin = self.GetPosition()
        self.delta = wx.Point(pos.x - origin.x, pos.y - origin.y)

    def OnMouseMove(self, evt):
        if evt.Dragging() and evt.LeftIsDown():
            pos = self.ClientToScreen(evt.GetPosition())
            newPos = (pos.x - self.delta.x, pos.y - self.delta.y)
            self.Move(newPos)

    def OnLeftUp(self, evt):
        if self.HasCapture():
            self.ReleaseMouse()

class Panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1, size=(200, 200,),style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW)
        self.CenterOnParent()


app = wx.App()

ShapedFrame(None,-1,None).Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Okay for my Edit question i just added a "panel.Layout()" after setting the sizer and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay i found out a solution, looking in **wx.coulor** since **2.9** they added **wxTransparentColour**

so i replaced :

```
r = wx.Region(self.bmp,"grey",30)
```

with:

```
r = wx.Region(self.bmp,wx.TransparentColour)
```

and it works fine ! Hope it will help other people too :)